# HP F4240 Drivers for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers

First and foremost: I am using a released version of Windows 7, not the RC, not the Beta, the "Signature Edition" from Hosting a Windows 7 Launch Party.

According to HP's website, the HP F4200 series is supported in Windows 7, The Scanning drivers install fine, but the printing drivers are no where to be found.

Anyone got some insight into where I can get Windows 7 x64 drivers for the Deskjet F4200 series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Windows Vista x64 drivers](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareList?os=2100&lc=en&dlc=ro&cc=ro&lang=ro&product=3571317). Windows vista drivers are compatible(the same) with windows 7 drivers.

Comment: I will try this out when I get home. - Thanks